# Split Multilanguage Strings in Half with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a string with simple Hebrew language text in half, and it should not split in the middle of a word or we get unwanted characters specially if we use vowels.

So I used this code from questions/8187429/split-strings-in-half-word-aware-with-php that does not work with Hebrew alphabet:

It's 'דְּבָרִים 8:3' or Deuteronomy 8:3 and I try to generate a thumbnail with it using ImageTtfText() GD2 function in PHP. 
I cant even use this in simple Hebrew with no vowels:

```
$text = "ויענך וירעבך ויאכלך את המן אשר לא ידעת ולא ידעון אבתיך  למען הודיעך כי לא על הלחם לבדו יחיה האדם—כי על כל מוצא פי יהוה יחיה האדם";

$middle = strrpos(substr($text, 0, floor(strlen($text) / 2)), ' ') + 1;

$string1 = substr($text, 0, $middle);  // "ויענך וירעבך ויאכלך את המן אשר לא ידעת ולא ידעון אבתיך  למען ה "
$string2 = substr($text, $middle);  // "�דיעך כי לא על הלחם לבדו יחיה האדם—כי על כל מוצא פי יהוה יחיה האדם"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the mb_ functions

```
<?php

    ini_set ( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );

    mb_internal_encoding ( 'UTF-8' );

    $text = "ויענך וירעבך ויאכלך את המן אשר לא ידעת ולא ידעון אבתיך  למען הודיעך כי לא על הלחם לבדו יחיה האדם—כי על כל מוצא פי יהוה יחיה האדם";



    $middle = mb_strrpos ( mb_substr ( $text, 0, floor ( mb_strlen( $text ) / 2 ) ), ' ' ) + 1;

    echo mb_substr ( $text, 0, $middle ) . "\n";
    echo mb_substr ( $text, $middle ) . "\n";

    ?>
```

Comment: The two half strings are clean. Thank You!